# How to read data via curl and return result into JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

How do I show 3 different direct links in file?

I have this link with 3 tag ids, low itag-5, medium-18, HD-22 look like following.

```
http://excample.com/'.$id.'/direct/5/'
http://excample.com/'.$id.'/direct/18/'
http://excample.com/'.$id.'/direct/22/'
```

The above links redirects with different quality.

I want output like the following URL

`http://server1.excample.com/vimotube.php?id=5lf9GWCQcMA`

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: i tried your last resolved question i want to 3 different redirect on one id and one place

Comment: ok please solve this issue

Comment: How will you check video type? like `"type":"video\/mp4",` Does `http://ytapi.com/api/'.$id.'/direct/5/'` also post video type?

Comment: i Copy only text from server1.yt-api.com no need type only i need 3 different quality redirect url your code only 1 redirect get when i copy this code 3 time and add quality tag 5-18-22 then your code is not work like this `<?php your code for tag 5?>``<?php your code for tag 22?>``<?php your code for tag 18?>` with same `$id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_encode` to return data into JSON format

**Full Code**

```
<?php

function get_final_url( $url, $timeout = 5 )
{
    $url = str_replace( "&amp;", "&", urldecode(trim($url)) );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );

    if ($response['http_code'] == 301 || $response['http_code'] == 302)
    {
        ini_set("user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");
        $headers = get_headers($response['url']);

        $location = "";
        foreach( $headers as $value )
        {
            if ( substr( strtolower($value), 0, 9 ) == "location:" )
                return get_final_url( trim( substr( $value, 9, strlen($value) ) ) );
        }
    }

    if
    (
        preg_match("/window\.location\.replace\('(.*)'\)/i", $content, $value) ||
        preg_match("/window\.location\=\"(.*)\"/i", $content, $value)
    )
    {
        return get_final_url ( $value[1] );
    }
    else
    {
        return $response['url'];
    }
}

if(!isset($_GET['id']))
exit('Invalid URL.');

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $url1 = 'http://excample.com/'.$id.'/direct/5/';
    $url2 = 'http://excample.com/'.$id.'/direct/18/';
    $url3 = 'http://excample.com/'.$id.'/direct/22/';

    $json = array('5' => array('quality' => '5', 'type' => 'video/x-flv', 'url' => get_final_url($url1)),'18' => array('quality' => '18', 'type' => 'video/mp4', 'url' => get_final_url($url2)),'22' => array('quality' => '22', 'type' => 'video/mp4', 'url' => get_final_url($url3)));

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: Please check your code return when i upload on site `http://server1.uplaytube.com/r/re.php?id=r4N2YN-la_E` only one url quality show visit this link check @Hassan

Comment: @SyedAliRazaNaqvi Please copy paste my full code from above answer in your file `re.php` and try again.

Comment: Please visit this re.php another file Your code first and now work ok, please tell me can i hide array if codefile.php not include with codefile.php?id=xxxxx please visit this link `http://server1.uplaytube.com/r/Ne.php?id=r4N2YN-la_E` with id and without `?id=r4N2YN-la_E` without id quality array show please hide when id not include with link @Hassan

Comment: Please accept my answer. If above code works for you. Second I did not understand, what you want in your last comment?

Comment: Bro Please visit this your code without ?id=xxxx if i want to hide all text if link not include with`?id=r4N2YN-la_E` `http://server1.uplaytube.com/r/Ne.php` please please

Comment: @SyedAliRazaNaqvi got it. I have updated my answer again. Please try again.

Comment: please add some text when text hide `url not completed`

Comment: @SyedAliRazaNaqvi you can't even do it yourself?

Comment: @SyedAliRazaNaqvi please accept my answer if works for you.

Comment: You Are Great Brothers Thanks @Hassan

Comment: Yes Brother ths is my Website

Comment: @SyedAliRazaNaqvi great work. Can you please share code of project with me?

Comment: Yes Why Not Brother Please contact me on my email i send you this my email `salishraza@gmail.com` and facebook id `alish.info`

Comment: Ok Bro please add me on facebook and please make a good responsive designe of this project

Comment: @SyedAliRazaNaqvi I have sent request by name "Muhammad Hassaan Ali"